# Starting thread again before its end

Tags: c#, multithreading

Maybe it's silly question, I am not very experienced with threads. I have program for encrypting and decrypting files. When I click button, list of files to work with from listbox is created, destination folder from folderbrowser dialog is set, than code is starting thread.
I was debugging program and I expected exception, when I am decrypting big file and before end of first task I am starting new decrypting.
But for my surprise both tasks are running simultaneously and without error to end.
So question is : is that possible or this behaviour can cause some problems?
Can I start thread with the same name before previous instance with the same name end?
Basically I am clicking button1 again before first task(decrypting big file) ended.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> seznamToDecrypt = new List<string>();
        string targetPath = "";
        DialogResult result2 = folderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog();
        if (result2 == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            targetPath = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;
            foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
                seznamToDecrypt.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            Thread t2 = new Thread(() => decryptFiles(seznamToDecrypt,       folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath,listPathForEdit));
            t2.IsBackground = true;
            t2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t2.Start();
```

Comment: The name of a thread is irrelevant. It's getting a new thread-id from system and you can start as much threads as you want with the same variable name (up to a max regarding of your system :) ).

Comment: Thanks, so it's multithreading with one thread, I like it :)

Comment: It is not just one thread, the faster the user can click, the more you've got running.  You are using fire-and-forget threading.  No, that isn't a very good strategy.  Things go wrong when the user picks the same file again and the previous decrypt operation isn't finished yet.  Kaboom, the exception crashes your program.  Or the file isn't readable because another process has a lock on the file.  Kaboom.  Nothing pretty about the user ending your program when the threads haven't finished yet either, you'll leave a half-written file behind on the disk.  Details, details.

Comment: Hans Passant:Thanks for reply, I am aware of this, next step are some controls like not to start decrypting the same file or dialog box if user really need end running thread and deleting not finished files. Or maybe I will only protect program to start new task before previous is done. There is also progress bar connected to decrypting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this may cause problems and yes, it is possible to start a new thread once the old thread ends, but you probably don't want to do that.

There are a few things you can do. One is start a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task) instead of starting a thread. The Task will run on its own thread, but the thread will be managed by the system.

Tasks can be cancelled (with some help from you), so you can cancel a task and start a new one when the user cancels the operation. Tasks can also be chained, using [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd270696), but I don't think it applies in your case - just cancel the first class and start a second one.